# Getting the InnerHTML of a div that is being hovered over

Tags: html, mysql, innerhtml

I have a list of titles with links. The titles and links are stored in a database and you can add one. Onload, I get the values from the database and echo them with a while function. As the div's aren't in the html file, I can't give them an id. 
I want to be able to delete values from he database at my will, by simply pressing one button. To do this, I'm gong to need something to go off to select the row to delete from the database. In the database, I have an id column, a title column and a link.

I need to be able to get the InnerHTML of the div they're hovering over so I can use 
`"Delete FROM $tbl_name WHERE title = 'InnerHTML of the active element'"`

I think I've over-complicated things but hopefully you can see what I want to do.

Also, how would I display an 'x' on hover and on click of that, delete the stuff. I couldn't do delete onclick of the div as otherwise, I couldn't visit the link.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the id?

Comment: It would be great if you could add more of your code to see the table structure for example. Anyway you can use jQuery to set up a [link](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) 'mouseover' function and then traverse the DOM to get the data you need. Also, remember to sanitize your input to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: It changes all the time. If they create 5 items, then delete the first one, the 1st one will have he I.D of 2

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on this tbh. If there is an easier value to use, then I'll go with it

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.  I use something similar on another project.

```
onmouseover="Javascript:ShowDeleteBox(this)"
onmouseout="Javascript:HideDeleteBox(this)"

var deleteText = "";
function ShowDeleteBox(this){
    var position = $(this).position();
    deleteText = this.innerHTML;
    $("#divDelete").html(result.d);
    $("#divDelete").css("display", "block");
    $("#divDelete").css("top", position.top + 25).css("left", position.left);
{

function HideDeleteBox(){
     $("#divDelete").css("display", "none");
}

function DeleteEntry(){
   //call code to delete from table here using the deleteText variable//
}
```

This is a hidden div that will hover

```
<div id="divDelete" style="display:none"><a href="DeleteEntry()">X</a></div>
```

Comment: `DeleteValue` referring to...? A variable?

Comment: DeleteValue() would be a javascript function that you would use to delete the value.  You could post to a form or use an ajax function to perform the delete in the table.

Comment: Where do I refer to the table, the row, the database? I'm not quite getting how this would work

Comment: Ok, so I have no idea why I thought it wouldn't be able to read `this.InnerHTML` but I done it with an alert box. Now I just need to display a `<span>x</span>` on hover. Then I'd need to return the InnerHTML of the original div when clicking on the 'x'. Could I use parent.InnerHTML, or some variant?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't like it:/ If I could just get the parent div's innerHTML I would be there. Here's the code that is looped...`    echo '<div class="more_item"><a href="'. $link .'">' . $title . '</a>
    <a href="index.php"><div class="deletebtn" onclick="alert();">x</div></div></a>';
`

Comment: I'm using the alert to find out how to get the parent innerHTML

Comment: Could you do something like <a href="'. ShowDeleteBox($title) .'">

Comment: No, I don't think so. I just need something along the lines of `parent.innerHTML`,but this returns 'undefined'.

Comment: What value are you trying to get?

Comment: The innerHTML of the parent of the 'x'